# Synchronize test runner with application under test

Tags: java, awt, native

I'm fixing custom test runner that use java.awt.Robot to manipulate applicaition under test.
After each simplest operation (mouse mote to some component, mouse click) I need test runner TO WAIT for application under test process the event. And ONLY AFTER this continue to check values, clicking some other buttons etc.
There is Robot.waitForIdle() function that could wait for event queue to become empty.
But I still have problems with synchronisation due to early checking values (let suppose values that is not calculated in some background threads but very EDT thread).
My guess this is due to Robot is not putting event to event queue directly but this is favour of underlying OS to put new event generated by Robot to JVM event queue.  And this native calls is asynchronous, means putting new event to event queue is not performed by any of JVM threads not like SwingUtilities.invokeLater() does.

Is it posible to implement some hook to determine or to wait for underlying OS put new event to event queue?
Am I missing anything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SunToolkit](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/sun/awt/SunToolkit.java.html)#realSync()